# how the camera moves whenever the location of Android Google Map changes

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner of android and java.

I am using the Android Google Map API.

`mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 18), 1000, null);`

Pressing a button using [animateCamera] implements the function of moving the camera to its current position.

I want the camera to keep up with my position.

[Thread] tried applying [animateCamera] using [sleep], but the Google Map stops.

How do I apply it in Android?

Comment: can you show you code it help out where have to put the mGoogleMap.moveCamera function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setOnCameraChangeListener on your google map:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(latlng);

map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
    // Move camera
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 10));
    // Remove listener to prevent position reset on camera move
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**check this code to first check location permission and then get current location and move camera in current location**

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            LatLng latLngOfMyLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            builder.include(latlng);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 8));

            return;
        }
```